# Performance Profiling Node.js showing different results (memory leak) on separate runs

Tags: node.js

I have a large nodejs server which opens remote DB connections and has a local redis.

I am investigating a possible memory leak in it and have it narrowed down to a specific function. I am making 5000 requests to the endpoint which then calls the function and each 10 seconds I am appending to a file the results of `process.memoryUsage()`.

The results that come are quite surprising in a sense that yesterday I was able to observe a memory leak in a sense that the memory ramps up during the 5000 requests and then it stays the same even though the server is idle for the next 20 minutes. This behaviour I confirmed in multiple runs.

Then I restarted my computer and having the same setup, same endpoint, the memory gets garbage collected.

I am running on Mac and I want to ask how would this be possible?